# Keyboard didn't work in Windows Explorer

Tags: keyboard, windows-explorer

My keyboard didn't work in Explorer and normal windows interface, for example type a folder name or shortcuts
But I can use it in another apps like Internet browser, office, etc

What's the problem?

Comment: Have you tried restarting?

Comment: Yes, many times @davidpostill